# Async issues when using JavaScript for API calls and writing data to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, hubspot

I'm trying to get data from Hubspot and write the JSON it returns to a file. I'm specifically using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/hubspot because it has a built-in failsafe for Hubspot's rate limits.

Unfortunately, I haven't been coding as much lately, and I ran up against an async issue with my code. It would be awesome if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here because I really need to get this script working.

My code:

```
const Hubspot = require('hubspot');
const fs = require('fs');
const hubspot = new Hubspot({ apiKey: 'apiKey' });

let engage = [];

const vid = [
'dummyId', 'dummyId2', 'dummyId3' 
];

function createFile () {
    fs.writeFile('./Engagements.json', engage, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Success!');
    });
}

(function () {
    for (i = 0; i <= vid.length; i++) {
        hubspot.engagements.getAssociated(hubspot.contacts, vid.i)
            .then(results => {engage.push(results)});
    }
    setTimeout(createFile, 10000);
})();
```

And here's the error message I'm getting:
`(node:37315) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 53)`

Comment: This won't fix your problem, but, `let engage = [];` should also be a `const`.

Comment: add a .catch after the .then so you can see what the error is that you are not handling

Comment: using `setTimeout(` to wait for an asynchronous process to finish is a disaster waiting to happen. You should instead collect all the promise generated by the for loop in an array and then use Promise.all to wait for them all to finish before calling `createFile`. First, however, you need to make the promise stop failing.

Comment: `vid.i` is undefined. It should be `vid[i]`

Comment: @KevinB The comment on adding avoiding setTimeout is helpful, but I would appreciate if you can answer with some code so I can see how to implement your suggestions.

Comment: @skellertor Same goes for your comment on using .catch after .then. It's helpful, but I'm not sure I'm capable of implementing it myself. I would love if you could answer the question with some code so I know how to implement the suggestion.

Comment: in the part where you are making the call to hubspot try passing in `vid[i]` instead of `vid.i`.  I bet you that's why hubspot is throwing an error.
```
hubspot.engagements.getAssociated(hubspot.contacts, vid[i])
            .then(results => {engage.push(results)});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a correct .catch implementation. You should still implement @KevinB suggestion he made in the comments after you find and fix the error.

```
(function() {
  for (i = 0; i <= vid.length; i++) {
    hubspot.engagements.getAssociated(hubspot.contacts, vid[i])
      .then(results => {
        engage.push(results);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
  setTimeout(createFile, 10000);
})();
```

Comment: It was helpful indeed! I'm still getting an error but a totally different one now. It's a 400 error this time. It unfortunately still says the error is undefined, but I think this is a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little difficult to debug from the snippet but from the error message you can try this:

```
(function() {
  for (i = 0; i <= vid.length; i++) {
    hubspot.engagements.getAssociated(hubspot.contacts, vid.i).then(results => {
      engage.push(results)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
  setTimeout(createFile, 10000);
})();
```

Basically, you need a catch so that we do not get an unhandled promise rejection... This might not solve the whole thing but it's a step in the right direction...

Comment: Huh. I changed my code to exactly what you have, but I'm still getting the exact same error.

Comment: That's a rather odd place to put .catch.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be waiting until all the promises return? Instead of depending upon the `setTimeout`, you might be better waiting for all the promises (look for `Promise.all`). You can also have a look at the article (https://davidwalsh.name/promises-results)

```
Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(() => undefined)));
```

In your case it will something like

```
(function () {
    var promises = [];
    for (i = 0; i <= vid.length; i++) {
        promises.push(hubspot.engagements.getAssociated(hubspot.contacts, vid.i));
    }
    Promise.all(promises.map(p => p.catch(e => e))).then(results => {
        results.forEach(result => {
            if (!(result instanceof Error)) {
                engage.push(result);
            }
        });
        createFile();
    });
})();
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for showing me how that code should look! It's super helpful. This did get fix my errors. Unfortunately, the file my `createFile` function creates has nothing in it. Any idea of what's going wrong there?

Comment: I see two issues with your `createFile` function. One you are not converting `engage` into json using `JSON.stringify` before writing. Also `fs.writeFile` will override the existing file (not sure if you intend it or not). If you dont intend to overwrite, you might want to look at calling `fs.truncate` and then `fs.writeFile`

Comment: Can you make sure that you are getting `results` back using the above code? Maybe confirm first by printing using `console.log`.

Comment: Also dont forget to `fs.close` after wrtiting